# Magento 2.3.7 developer mode : I need to regenerate my static content all the time

Tags: magento2, frontend, static-content, apache

**Env :**

- Magento 2.3.7
- PHP 7
- VM on Linux

I'm facing an issue : my instance of Magento 2 is in developer mode. But I need, all the time, to redeploy static content (like JS and CSS ; with -f argument) on editing, so It's pretty counterproductive...

In my `app/etc/di.xml` file, I've **Symlink** for `view_preprocessed`. But the generated `pub/static` files are not linked to any file : it seems to be statics, like a copy. I don't understand because the advantage to be in developer mode is to avoid this pub static files generation after editing ... My files are not versioned.

I have `MAGE_MODE` to `developer` in my `app/etc/env.php` file.
In my `.htaccess` file in pub directory, I have `SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer` . And the displayed mode in CLI are developer.

Do I have to edit my Apache configuration ? I apprechiate your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you run command

```
$ bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

All static content will be deployed (created copy) independent on mode

Remove `pub/static` and `var/view_preprocessed` and flush cache and after you've open front and the system will create symlinks in pub/static except some generated files

If you want to build on fly CSS you can configure grunt and run it in watch mode. See [Compile LESS using Grunt](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html)

If you are modify something like `requirejs-config.js` you will need to flush cache

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've deleted pub/static/adminhtml content and frontend (just content not folder). And after cache clean, I do not have any content in pub static folder.. except require js config file

Comment: You can check a mode with `bin/magento deploy:mode:show` command. What is the OS and FS are you use? Magento should generates symlinks. What do you think when you load backend? Do you have properly configured HTTP server for serve static content?

Comment: I'm in developer mode, deploy:mode:show command tell me also this. As mentionned i'm using Linux (Ubuntu). I don't know if my server is correctly configured, how can I see that ?

Comment: When you load admin with empty pub/static do you have a correct styles and js? What HTTP server are you use?

Comment: On admin pages I've the same result than in front : no JS and CSS loaded/generated. I'm using Apache 2

Comment: See official documentation [Apache PreRequirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/apache.html). Static files if missed should be requests to `pub/static.php`

Comment: I have the exact same .htaccess file than this one https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.7-patch-33664/pub/static/.htaccess. Are we talking about the htaccess file in pub/static ? For my apache2.conf file, I can't Order allow,deny for /var/www bc it raise me 403

Comment: Please read carefully Magento documentation and to be sure you are use correct paths and all `.htaccess` files in place. The issue is related to Apache configuration. As alternative - you can use `nginx` + `php-fpm` instead. I cannot help to solve your issues with apache without see configs, etc

Comment: Yes, I have check Apache config. Here is my Apache 2.4 configuration https://ctxt.io/2/AADg4tU5Ew

Comment: Please see **Important: Apache rewrites and .htaccess** from [Apache PreRequirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/apache.html) documentation! You have `AllowOverride None` for `Directory /var/www/`.

Comment: Indeed, but when I put **AllOverride to 'All'** for **Directory /var/www**, I've the same behavior : on removing the content for pub/static/frontend and adminhtml and cache clean, the static content for JS and CSS files is not created... (I've restart Apache2 service). I notice my project in var/www folder in a symlink to another folder, I add the other folder to see if the problem was here, but I've the same behavior.